# Outside dwarves run into enemies during attacks

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In my fort, I've attracted a good number of fisherdwarves who spend their entire day out fishing in the river or ponds. The only issue is that whenever I'm attacked, there seems to be no way to get them back inside my fort's burrow quickly enough. This is the worst when a werebeast attacks, as it'll usually stay by my fort entrance attacking (and infecting) everyone who slowly walks by it on their way back. By the time my military can get to it, there's already 3 dwarves bleeding/dead by my tunnel, really ruining the ambiance of the place.

This is getting especially annoying seeing as my entryway is armed to the teeth with traps, but I never get to use it unless I want to sacrifice all my fishers/wood haulers.

Is there any way to better handle my lockdown plans, or should I just give up on fishing completely?

Comment: There's probably no good way to speed the fishermen up.  At a guess, you'd need to give them a local bolthole to hide in, or get your military to hang out closer.  Or for the more dwarfy solution, "engineer" your lakes and streams closer to the fort.

Comment: Your mindset is completely wrong. Dwarves should not be cowering from ANYTHING. Clad your most badass miner from head to toe in adamantine and give Urist McBait his trusty steel pickaxe. Then go catch some fishies, for the Bloodgod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Create walled, and roofed fishing zones.**

You set the zone where they are allowed to fish with <kbd>i</kbd>
Make sure it includes both water and a place to stand.

Wall it off, and for extra safty (from birds etc) put a roof on it.

Connect that to your main fort by a tunnel. 
And only by a tunnel (they way they won't try to short cut across land.)

Bonus: You can put your *fisherys* closer to that fishing point so not so much carting is done. (only the (theoretically) lighter cleaned fish).
And then you put your *craftshops* near that to use up the shell etc etc

Comment: For extra safety, you can alter zone options to allow fishing ONLY from the zone (default is 'prefer zone', which means they'll occasionally go to a different pond.); iirc, it's o > z > f